# In my vimrc how to test if a plugin is installed?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system

My use case is the following, but I think a general solution, working for as
many plugins as possible would be preferable:

I use the [submodes plugin](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode) to create a
submode handling windows. In my `.vimrc` I have several lines containing calls
to functions defined by this plugin (like that:)

```
" The submode is entered whith <Leader>k and exited with <Leader>
call submode#enter_with('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<Leader>k', ':echo "windows mode"<C
call submode#leave_with('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<Leader>')
" Change of windows with hjkl
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'j', '<C-w>j')
```

When I am on a machine where I use my `.vimrc` but I haven't installed the
plugin yet, I get errors on Vim starting: `E117: Unknown function :submode#enter_with`.

This is normal that this happen since the plugin isn't installed, Vim can't know
the function. But the message on my shell necessitating a key press to disappear is pretty annoying.

---

To avoid that I've tried several things

- Some (good) plugins declare a variable `g:loaded_pluginname` which is
  accessible at the time of the `.vimrc` sourcing and can be used to test if
  the plugin exists. Unfortunately submode (and other plugins) doesn't 
  provide such a variable (nor any variable available at `.vimrc` sourcing time).
- Of course, I could use `:silent!` in front of all the lines causing the
  message to mute them. The problem is that it doesn't feels really clean to
  proceed this way: I'd like keeping the potential error messages when the
  plugin is installed.
- The last solution I've found is to check if the file defining the plugin
  exists and put the call to the function in this if:

  ```
  if (filereadable($HOME . "/.vim/plugged/vim-submode/autoload/submode.vim"))
  ```

  The fact is that it doesn't seem efficient nor reliable to me.

**Thus I'm looking for the most generic way to programmatically test from my `.vimrc` if a plugin
is already installed.**

Comment: Maybe you could test the existence of the functions before calling them. For example something like: `if exists(*submode#enter_with)`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the single quotes: `if exists('*submode#enter_with')`

Comment: @user9433424: I don't really understand why but `exists('*submode#enter_with')` always returns false (no matter if the plugin is installed or not) in my vimrc.

Comment: Maybe that's because your plugin uses autoloading: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/53.html If that's the case, the function is only defined when you call it for the first time, and my answer was not really useful for your particular case, sorry.

Comment: Yes I think autoloading is the reason. And no need to be sorry you tried to help it's all that matter :)

Comment: I think checking if plugin's path exists is your best bet. This seems to be the case also with `vim-plug` plugin manager - see for example https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim#L2003. (BTW using it could simplify things for you, I think you just have to add a 'PlugInstall' or similar command to your `vimrc` end).

Comment: @VanLaser: Thanks for your link. I'm a little bit disappointed there isn't a "cleaner" way to test that. I'll probably make my own function inspired on vim-plug.

Comment: @statox - You're welcome. I wonder, couldn't one use `try` and `catch` Vim keywords when calling `submode#enter_with`? (at the 1st call, perhaps).

Comment: @VanLaser: Damn! How did I not think of it earlier whereas I already use it somewhere else in my `.vimrc`! Of course `try` and `catch`are perfect for that. I just solved my problem with them. You can post that as an answer if you want: it is not dependent of the installation path nor of the plugin manager used, I don't need to write a new function and if I want to do nothing when an error pops, the `catch` clause can be empty.

Comment: @statox - cool then! I don't use `try` and `catch` myself; from my part is perfect if you post your solved problem (or relevant lines) as answer :)

Comment: "Some (good) plugins declare a variable g:loaded_pluginname which is accessible at the time of the .vimrc sourcing and can be used to test if the plugin exists."  This isn't true.  Plugins are loaded after the user's vimrc (since the user's vimrc may need to let some variables to configure the plugin, are manipulate `'runtimepath'`).  The purpose of the variables is two-fold.  To prevent re-loading the file and to allow the user to disable loading of the plugin, typically be putting `let g:loaded_pluginname=1` in their vimrc.

Answer (score 5):

Normally `exists('*submode#enter_with')` can be used, however it was returning false in my case.

So [@VanLaser](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/in-my-vimrc-how-to-test-if-a-plugin-is-installed#comment12478_7581) suggested a pretty simple solution using the `try` and `catch` vimscript instruction to execute the lines which echoed errors when the plugin wasn't installed.

For now I use this solution, it doesn't allow to determine if a plugin is installed or not but at least my instructions are run when it's possible and I got rid of the error messages when the instructions can't be executed:

```
try
    " Create a submode to handle windows
    " The submode is entered whith <Leader>k and exited with <Leader>
    call submode#enter_with('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<Leader>k', ':echo "windows mode"<CR>')
    call submode#leave_with('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<Leader>')
    " Change of windows with hjkl
    call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'j', '<C-w>j')
catch
    "echo "The functions can't be executed"
endtry
```

I think I could even put the following in the `catch` block to automatically try to install the missing plugin.

```
catch
    echo "vim-submode is not installed, trying to install it"
    PlugInstall vim-submode
endtry
```

Answer (score 1):

For autoload plugins i proceed in two steps.

First i test whether the function exists. If not i execute `:runtime autoload/path/pluginname.vim` and i test again whether the function exists.